# JavaFX 8 How to dispose a Node object on a JavaFX Line chart

Tags: java, charts, javafx, javafx-8

I've a moving line chart (live chart where the data moves each second i.e., the lower bound and the upper bound as well as the series that displays the line are updated each second). Once every minute, I also display a text object anchored to a particular x-y value on the chart.

[image: Text object]

Each second the entire chart gets updated and so does this text object (the text object moves each second)

Issue:

The text object is not moving past the lower bound

[image: Doesn't move past lower bound]
[image]

I'm creating the text object and then adding it to a [XYChart.Data](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Data.html) point using the setNode() API, then setting this data point to a [XYChart.Series](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Series.html) and setting the style on it.

**I'm not able to figure out a way to dispose this text object.**

**Code:**
Creating Text Object and setting it to the XYChart.Data object

```
Text moaLabel = new Text("MHRext\nUS1\nUnknown");

Data<Date, Integer> moaPlot = new Data<>();
moaPlot.setNode(moaLabel);
moaPlot.setXValue(xPosition);
moaPlot.setYValue(yPosition);
```

Adding the Data object to the series object

```
textSeries.getData().add(moaPlot);
```

CSS

```
.chart-series-line-text-mode {    
    -fx-stroke-width: 0px;
    -fx-stroke: #FFFFFF;    
    -fx-effect: null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

The approach is to check if the `moaPlot.getXValue().equals(lowerBound)` then remove it from the `textSeries` list.

In my case since the chart moves every second, I've the following code in an scheduler that runs every second.

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(()->{
    textSeries.getData().removeIf(moa -> (moa.getXValue().before(lowerBound))); 
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```